# Prestashop cUrl Login

Tags: php, curl, prestashop

I'm trying to log-in as customer using cUrl method in Prestashop.

When I send my cUrl request, my values are inserted in the log-in form but the form is not submitted.

Here my code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/prestashop/login';
$fields = array(
       'submitLogin' => 1,
       'email' => 'wajid_rea@gmail.com',
       'passwd' => '123456',
   );

$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
//print 'yes123';die;
$response = json_decode($result);
print_r($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Hello, 
did you find a way to achieve that? I can't figure out how to login to Prestashop using cUrl

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/prestashop/login';
$fields = array(
   'submitLogin' => 1,
   'email' => 'wajid_rea@gmail.com',
   'passwd' => '123456',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be carrefull with the first uppercase letter **S**ubmitLogin.

I've just waste one day of work because of this!

Then, i decided to prevent other users make same error.